# Find the newest ID with historical ID

Tags: sql, teradata

I currently have the following scenario : I have an ID(primary key) changing over a period of time. During the process I need to find out the newest ID with historical ID as reference.

For ex:

```
Hist ID    New ID
123        234
234        345
345        456
```

In the above sample data, 123 is the known historical key and I need to retrieve the current ID i.e. 456.

Any suggestion on how this could be implemented via sql would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should create a column to store your hist ID in order to retrieve it later

Comment: using `MAX()` you can find the newest ID if it is auto incremented column

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. The answer may use product specific functionality.

Comment: Hopefully oracle, because this looks like a connect by prior

Comment: @jarlh   The database is Teradata.

Comment: You want a recusive query. Check if your DBMS supports recursive common table expression

Comment: A google for TERADATA RECURSIVE QUERY brings plenty of hits

Comment: How do you know that `New ID` 456 has anything to do with `Hist ID` 123?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bteradata%5D+recursive - Here are some posts that explain recursion in Teradata. Once you take a crack at constructing the syntax, update your question with your SQL and we can help you further.

Comment: Is this for a single known `Hist ID`? Then put the recursive Select in a Macro with the ID as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recursive query` and `parameterized macro` to get your desired result.

Create `macro` as below.

```
REPLACE MACRO Find_New_Id(old_id INT) AS( WITH RECURSIVE id_map(hist_id, new_id, depth) AS
  (SELECT hist_id,
          new_id,
          0
   FROM id_tbl
   WHERE hist_id = :old_id
   UNION ALL SELECT im.hist_id,
                    it.new_id,
                    depth+1
   FROM id_map im
   JOIN id_tbl it ON im.new_id = it.hist_id
   AND im.hist_id <> it.new_id)
SELECT id_m.new_id
FROM id_map id_m JOIN
  (SELECT Max(depth) AS Depth_val
   FROM id_map) AS tbl_depth
ON id_m.depth = tbl_depth.Depth_val;);
```

Then execute it with `Hist Id` as input(in your case its `123`. You can also use any other `hist Id` i.e. `234`, `345`).

```
EXEC Find_New_Id(123);
```

It will generate result as below.

```
new_Id
-------
456
```

Hope this will help.

**Edit:**

After dnoeth suggestions, following is the simpler version of initial query.

```
   REPLACE MACRO Find_New_Id(old_id INT) AS( WITH RECURSIVE id_map(hist_id, new_id, depth) AS
  (SELECT hist_id,
          new_id,
          0
   FROM id_tbl
   WHERE hist_id = :old_id
   UNION ALL SELECT im.hist_id,
                    it.new_id,
                    depth+1
   FROM id_map im
   JOIN id_tbl it ON im.new_id = it.hist_id
   AND im.hist_id <> it.new_id)
SELECT TOP 1 new_id
FROM id_map
ORDER BY depth DESC;);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add column as date_created and add datetime when data added. After that you can find `top 1 from NewID` with `date_created DESC` filter on table.